# Follow each link of a page and scrape content, Scrapy + Selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium, scrapy

[This](http://app.bjdx.gov.cn/cms/daxing/lookliuyan_bjdx.jsp) is the website I'm working on. On each page, there are 18 posts in a table. I want to access each post and scrape its content, and repeat this for the first 5 pages.

My approach is to make my spider to scrape all links in the 5 pages and iterate over them to get the content. Because the "next page" button and certain text in each post is written by JavaScript, I use Selenium and Scrapy. I ran my spider and could see that Firefox webdriver displays the first 5 pages, but then the spider stopped without scraping any content. Scrapy returns no error message either.

Now I suspect that the failure may be due to:

1) No link is stored into all_links.

2) Somehow parse_content did not run.

My diagnosis may be wrong and I need help with finding the problem. Thank you very much!

This is my spider:

```
import scrapy
from bjdaxing.items_bjdaxing import BjdaxingItem
from selenium import webdriver
from scrapy.http import TextResponse 
import time

all_links = [] # a global variable to store post links


class Bjdaxing(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "daxing"

    allowed_domains = ["bjdx.gov.cn"] # DO NOT use www in allowed domains
    start_urls = ["http://app.bjdx.gov.cn/cms/daxing/lookliuyan_bjdx.jsp"] # This has to start with http

    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

    def parse(self, response):
        self.driver.get(response.url) # request the start url in the browser         

        i = 1

        while i <= 5: # The number of pages to be scraped in this session

            response = TextResponse(url = response.url, body = self.driver.page_source, encoding='utf-8') # Assign page source to response. I can treat response as if it's a normal scrapy project.           

            global all_links
            all_links.extend(response.xpath("//a/@href").extract()[0:18])

            next = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(u'//a[text()="\u4e0b\u9875\xa0"]') # locate "next" button
            next.click() # Click next page            
            time.sleep(2) # Wait a few seconds for next page to load. 

            i += 1


    def parse_content(self, response):
        item = BjdaxingItem()
        global all_links
        for link in all_links: 
            self.driver.get("http://app.bjdx.gov.cn/cms/daxing/") + link

            response = TextResponse(url = response.url, body = self.driver.page_source, encoding = 'utf-8')

            if len(response.xpath("//table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/text()").extract() > 0):
                item['title'] =     response.xpath("//table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/text()").extract()
            else: 
                item['title'] = ""    

            if len(response.xpath("//table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/text()").extract() > 0):
                item['netizen'] =    response.xpath("//table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/text()").extract()
            else: 
                item['netizen'] = ""    

            if len(response.xpath("//table/tbody/tr[3]/td[4]/text()").extract() > 0):
                item['sex'] = response.xpath("//table/tbody/tr[3]/td[4]/text()").extract()
            else: 
                item['sex'] = ""   

            if len(response.xpath("//table/tbody/tr[5]/td[2]/text()").extract() > 0):
                item['time1'] = response.xpath("//table/tbody/tr[5]/td[2]/text()").extract()
            else: 
                item['time1'] = ""

            if len(response.xpath("//table/tbody/tr[11]/td[2]/text()").extract() > 0):
                item['time2'] =   response.xpath("//table/tbody/tr[11]/td[2]/text()").extract()
            else: 
                item['time2'] = "" 

            if len(response.xpath("//table/tbody/tr[7]/td[2]/text()").extract()) > 0:
                question = "".join(response.xpath("//table/tbody/tr[7]/td[2]/text()").extract())
                item['question'] = "".join(map(unicode.strip, question))
            else: item['question'] = ""  

            if len(response.xpath("//table/tbody/tr[9]/td[2]/text()").extract()) > 0:
                reply = "".join(response.xpath("//table/tbody/tr[9]/td[2]/text()").extract()) 
                item['reply'] = "".join(map(unicode.strip, reply))
            else: item['reply'] = ""    

            if len(response.xpath("//table/tbody/tr[13]/td[2]/text()").extract()) > 0:
                agency = "".join(response.xpath("//table/tbody/tr[13]/td[2]/text()").extract())
                item['agency'] = "".join(map(unicode.strip, agency))
            else: item['agency'] = ""    

            yield item
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple problems and possible improvements here:

- you don't have any "link" between the `parse()` and the `parse_content()` methods
- using `global` variables is usually a bad practice
- you don't need `selenium` here at all. To follow the pagination you just need to make a POST request to the same url providing the `currPage` parameter

The idea is to use `.start_requests()` and create a list/queue of requests to handle the pagination. Follow the pagination and gather the links from the table. Once the queue of requests is empty, switch to following the previously gathered links. Implementation:

```
import json
from urlparse import urljoin

import scrapy


NUM_PAGES = 5

class Bjdaxing(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "daxing"

    allowed_domains = ["bjdx.gov.cn"] # DO NOT use www in allowed domains

    def __init__(self):
        self.pages = []
        self.links = []

    def start_requests(self):
        self.pages = [scrapy.Request("http://app.bjdx.gov.cn/cms/daxing/lookliuyan_bjdx.jsp",
                                     body=json.dumps({"currPage": str(page)}),
                                     method="POST",
                                     callback=self.parse_page,
                                     dont_filter=True)
                      for page in range(1, NUM_PAGES + 1)]

        yield self.pages.pop()

    def parse_page(self, response):
        base_url = response.url
        self.links += [urljoin(base_url, link) for link in response.css("table tr td a::attr(href)").extract()]

        try:
            yield self.pages.pop()
        except IndexError:  # no more pages to follow, going over the gathered links
            for link in self.links:
                yield scrapy.Request(link, callback=self.parse_content)

    def parse_content(self, response):
        # your parse_content method here
```

Comment: thank you a lot for the solution. I've tested it and it worked well. However, I'm still struggling to understand how `yield self.pages.pop()` inside `parge_page()` triggered `except`. My understanding is that each time, `start_requests()` puts a page in `self.pages`, and `self.pages.pop()` in `parse_page()` takes it out. So by the fifth time, `self.pages` should not be empty but has one page in it, and `yield self.pages.pop()` should yield it. But apparently my understanding is incorrect. Could you help me know where I was wrong?

Comment: @JosephZhou sure, the `self.pages` has an internal request queue inside. Each time `pop()` called on it, there is one more request less in the queue. When the queue is empty and there are no requests inside, `pop()` would produce an `IndexError` - pop from an empty list error which for us is a sign that we can now start following the links. Hope this makes things clear. Thanks.

Comment: thanks for your quick response. But I guess I'm still missing something. Aren't there five requests totally in `self.pages` and five calls by `pop()`? How can this give a list error? Only a sixth `pop()` will call on an empty queue, right?

Comment: @JosephZhou yup, the last request callback would make a pop from an empty list, sorry if I am not understanding what you are not understanding - put the prints into the spider and watch the `pages` value..

Comment: no problem. But I just realized a new problem with the spider. By carefully examining `self.links`, I found that although it contains 90 links, there are only 18 unique links, all else being duplicates. So it seems that the spider did not follow pages but crawl the first page five times.

Comment: @JosephZhou okay, please see if it makes sense to create a separate question. Make sure you provide all of the required details. Thanks.